# Using location typeahead in facebook application

Tags: facebook, location, typeahead

Is there any way to leverage facebook's location typeahead in a facebook application?  They have a great location typeahead feature on their site, but I can't find any documentation around how to use it in an app.

Comment: 2 months. Any solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

I created one using their graph api, but it's too slow. Taking about 1 second for refreshing the list as the user types new characters.